# Getting value of element using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to get the value of

tag

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 text-center category">
        <li class="main-li" id="<?php if ($i == 0) {
            $i = 1;
            echo 'active-nav';
        } ?>" value="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <?php echo $category ?>
        </li>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is my jquery

```
$(".category").click(() => {
    var category_id = $('li #active-nav').attr('value');
    alert(category_id);
});
```

Anybody can help be get the value when i click each category div

Comment: Id of an element should be unique, So please try to get value based on `this` LIke `var category_id = $(this).attr('value');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. It should be:

```
"li#active-nav"
```

...without the space. "li #active-nav" is searching for an element with id="active-nav" within a list item

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong selector..Should have done this.

```
var category_id = $('.category #active-nav').attr('value');
```